# creating a log from a series of batchfile executables

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a stdout, stderr, and echo out log file.

In a task scheduler, I call a batch file. say bat1.bat
bat1.bat calls other batch files.  say bat1a.bat, bat1b.bat, and so forth.

each of those files call python scripts: python \UNCshare\folder\script.py jobname (there's 1200 of these calls spread across the batch files.

so for example:

```
task scheduler calls bat1.bat
bat1.bat
|-bat1a.bat
 |-python \\uncshare\folder\script.py jobname
 |-python \\uncshare\folder\script.py jobname
|-bat1b.bat
 |-python \\uncshare\folder\script.py jobname
 |-python \\uncshare\folder\script.py jobname
etc....
```

How do I tell them all to output to the same log file. and secondly, how do I set the log file name so I can use a date in the file name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a great way to do this in windows batch files.
It's a lot easier to do if you were to use another technology.  Since you're already using python, you could have a python script called by the task scheduler that:

- opened a file with the date in the filename
- used subprocess.Popen to run your batch files with stderr and stdout redirected to that log file

I think anything that you echo in your batch files will go to stdout